# Placing a span tag within an anchor in Haml

Tags: haml

I am new to Haml and am trying to simply place a span tag within an anchor link like so:

```
.text Here is some copy.
= link_to 'Visit website', 'https://websitelink.com/', class: 'link'
   %span
```

This is throwing an error, "`syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end`"

How Do I perform this simple task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails’ [`link_to` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) accepts either the link text as a parameter or as the result of a block.

In this case you probably want something like this:

```haml
= link_to 'https://websitelink.com/', class: 'link' do
  %span Visit website
```

Note the `do` indicating a block, and that there are only two parameters to the method, the “Visit Website” text has been moved into the block.

This renders:

```html
<a class="link" href="https://websitelink.com/"><span>Visit website</span>
</a>
```